# How to move a sprite without causing fps lag

Tags: swift3, sprite-kit, xcode8

I'm creating a spritekit game and I'm fairly new to swift. I want have two buttons that make the player either move right or left. When a button is pressed, say the left button, the sprite must start moving to the left without stopping. When it hits the left wall it changes direction and moves right towards the other wall, and so on... I managed to let the sprite do this by using the update function. Each time it was called it would check whether the player is pressing a button and it would move the sprite accordingly, however, it cause somewhat FPS lag (FPS would drop to 50).

I tried using SKActions like MoveBy and MoveTo but couldn't recreate what I wanted the sprite to do.

So my question is: How can I make the sprite move the way I want using the two buttons and not cause FPS lag. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Here are the functions I called in the update function that worked but caused lag.

```
func moveRight() {
    sprite.xScale = 1
    sprite.position.x += 4
}

func moveLeft() {
    sprite.xScale = -1
    sprite.position.x -= 4
}
```

Comment: Obviously something like this is not going to cause lag, take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve if you want to get real answers instead of guesses from people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

It runs the move action forever when the button is pressed and when the button is released it removes the action

This will get the player moving hopefully without dropping frame rate. To change the direction on the sprite when it hits a wall you will have to check for collisions. When it hits the wall you can check if it's the leftMove or rightMove action that is being applied then remove that action and start the opposite one.

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        if(leftButton.contains(location) { // check if left button was pressed
            moveLeft()
        } else if(rightButton.contains(location) { //check if right button was pressed
            moveRight()
        }
    }
}

func moveLeft() {
    //Check if it's already moving left, if it is return out of function
    if((sprite.action(forKey: "leftMove")) != nil) {
        return
    }
    //Check if its moving right, if it is remove the action
    if((sprite.action(forKey: "rightMove")) != nil) {
        sprite.removeAllActions()
    }
    //Create and run the left movement action
    let action = SKAction.move(by: -100, duration: 1)
    sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action), withKey: "leftMove")
}

func moveRight() {
    //Check if it's already moving right, if it is return out of function
    if((sprite.action(forKey: "rightMove")) != nil) {
        return
    }
    //Check if its moving left, if it is remove the action
    if((sprite.action(forKey: "leftMove")) != nil) {
        sprite.removeAllActions()
    }
    //Create and run the right movement action
    let action = SKAction.move(by: 100, duration: 1)
    sprite.run(SKAction.repeatForever(action), withKey: "rightMove")
}
```

Comment: move functions are called but sprite doesnt move... What could be wrong?

Comment: Okay the move by value could be really low which makes it look like its not moving. Try changing the 0.4 to something silly like 1000 and see if it moves. Also make sure the run action is being called on your sprite you want to move.

Comment: Ok that was part of the problem I changed the value to be bigger. It moves now when i press a button. When I release it keeps on moving (which is right), but then when I press a button after that it doesnt move, it just moves a little bit - in the opposite direction of the button direction. I don't know what is going on

Comment: So when the button is realised it should carry on moving until another button is pressed?

Comment: Yes the sprite must always be moving on the horizontal axis. When a button is preseed its direction can be chenged